# Change GraphQL field type without breaking clients

Tags: graphql

I've got several resolvers that use this signature:

```
query MyQuery($take: Int) {
  findMany(take: $take) {
    id
  }
}
```

Now I want to start using a custom scalar, which is also an Int, but does some other internal validation (max value for example). So I create a MinMaxScalar as a custom GraphQLScalarType, and change the @Field((_type) => Int) to @Field((_type) => MinMaxScalar).

Is there any way to do this without breaking old clients? It seems since graphql doesn't have input unions of scalar types, the only choice is to rename the field during the migration, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your existing query definitions from:

```
Query {
  findMany(take: Int!) SomeType
}
```

to:

```
Query {
  findMany(take: Int, freshTake MinMaxScalar) SomeType
}
```

Then have the query resolver look for one or the other (but not both) arguments. Your old clients should continue to work using the existing `take` input variable will newer clients use the `freshTake` variable.

You might also log uses of the older input variable so that you can determine when to remove it from your code altogether.